# How twig set block in array

Tags: php, twig

i need make block in towig and set
for example:
    {%set fo.bar%}
       hi
    {%endset%}
but has error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block" expected) in "content_cp/home/menue.html" at line 1. in /home/test/Twig/lib/Twig/TokenStream.php on line
```

Answer (score 1):

Twig doesn't allow object `.` notation within `set` tag usage.
Try to use `merge` function to override `bar` property of `fo` object:

```
 {% set fo = fo|merge({'bar': 'hi'}) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put something like this and I don't think you can put `.`s in the block id.

```
{% block body %}
    <p>Hello</p>
{% endblock %}
```